# Handlebars.js and HTML table displays [object Object] instead of values

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I got some problems with handlebars and html tables:

```
{ 
  weekdays: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'] 

}

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {{#each weekdays}}
                        <th>{{this}}</th>
                        {{/each}}
                    </tr>        
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This code works on [tryhandlebars](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/).

When using a template it works fine with lists and plain, but when I try the same with table headings and data it just displays: [object Object] instead.
The code is on: [jsfidde](https://jsfiddle.net/ouhd7sLg/)

Comment: do weekdays.yourAttribute to display the attribute of your object.

Comment: what is the contents of the object?

Comment: they are both arrays. weekdays with strings, days with int

Comment: If the same code works with the [tryhandlebars](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/) website, then it's 100% something else in your code that you're not showing here. Perhaps you are overwriting `weekdays` elsewhere?

Comment: I reproduced the example on jsfidde and added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use the html to generate the template but mustache statements can generate invalid html which the browser tries to correct for.

If you look at the html that is passed to handlebars, you get this:

```
                    {{#each weekdays}}

                    {{/each}}
                <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!-- displays [object Object] with <template> tag --><th>{{this}}</th></tr>        
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The contents of a `script` tag are not parsed in the same manner so you don't have a corrupted template.

In generally I'd recommend that you use precompiled templates rather than inlining them into your html, but if you do inline them in your html, you need to use the `script` tag.

Comment: Same answer cross posted here: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1133

Answer (score -1):

it is because you're just dumping the individual weekday object, not the named property.

you'll want to change this:

```
                        {{#each days}}
                        <td>{{this}}</td>
                        {{/each}}
```

to something like this:

```
                        {{#each days}}
                        <td>{{this.dayName}}</td>
                        {{/each}}
```

or whatever the property name on the object is.

Comment: Thanks, but its an array, and the code works outside the table environment.